# Why operator 'as' is slower then 'is'?

Tags: c#, reflection, operators

I have next class:

```
public class A
{
    public int MyProperty { get; set; }
}
```

And the following code in Main:

```
object obj = new A();

Stopwatch sw = Stopwatch.StartNew();
var res = obj as A;
if (res != null)
{
    res.MyProperty = 10;
    Console.WriteLine("obj is A (as)" + sw.Elapsed);
}
sw.Stop();

Stopwatch sw2 = Stopwatch.StartNew();
if (obj.GetType() == typeof(A))
{
    A a = (A)obj;
    a.MyProperty = 10;
    Console.WriteLine("obj is A (GetType)" + sw2.Elapsed);
}
sw2.Stop();

Stopwatch sw3 = Stopwatch.StartNew();
var isA = obj is A;
if (isA)
{
    A a = (A)obj;
    a.MyProperty = 19;
    Console.WriteLine("obj is A (is)" + sw3.Elapsed);
}
sw3.Stop();

Console.ReadKey();
```

The results are:

```
obj is A (as) 00:00:00.0000589
obj is A (GetType) 00:00:00.0000024
obj is A (is) 00:00:00.0000006
```

The point is that operator 'is' works always faster than 'as'. Why 'as' is slower than 'is'? Even GetType() faster than 'as'. What stands for 'as' operator that cause such delays comparing to 'is' and GetType().

Comment: Because `as` performs `is` before casting the object or returning `null`?

Comment: Hope this link is helpful http://brijbhushan.net/2011/03/11/is-vs-as-operators-performance-implications/

Comment: What happens if you switch the order in which you run your tests? If I put `GetType` as the first test, all of a sudden *it's* the slowest (and there's nothing to choose between `is` and `as`)

Comment: You should average out 1 million executions of each one. Don't do anything else until you're through with all of it, then output whatever data you need.

Comment: @Nolonar - actually, in either case, the [`isinst`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.emit.opcodes.isinst.aspx) instruction is used in the IL. `is` checks whether the result is null. `as` can skip this step, because it just needs to use the result (which is either a correct object instance or null)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it could be due to the fact that you are also setting `MyProperty`, so the first time you do that the property setter is JIT-compiled.

Try running this code, with and without the commented lines, and check the difference:

```
    object obj = new A();

    // uncomment these lines and see the difference
    // A tmp = new A();
    // tmp.MyProperty = 100;

    Stopwatch sw = Stopwatch.StartNew();
    var res = obj as A;
    if (res != null) {
        res.MyProperty = 10;
    }
    sw.Stop();
    Console.WriteLine("as : " + sw.Elapsed);

    Stopwatch sw2 = Stopwatch.StartNew();
    if (obj.GetType() == typeof(A)) {
        A a = (A)obj;
        a.MyProperty = 10;
    }
    sw2.Stop();
    Console.WriteLine("GetType : " + sw2.Elapsed);

    Stopwatch sw3 = Stopwatch.StartNew();
    var isA = obj is A;
    if (isA) {
        A a = (A)obj;
        a.MyProperty = 19;
    }
    sw3.Stop();
    Console.WriteLine("is : " + sw3.Elapsed);
```

Comment: Thanks for sample! I tested it and I found the difference you are talking about. Can you describe why first setting of property slower than others?

Answer (score 4):

I would guess that it's the first `Console.Write` that has to open a stream to the console, so that takes a lot more time.

Anyway, writing to the console takes so much more time than doing a cast, so you can't draw any conclusion at all about the castings from your test.

Doing the casts a billion times and don't write anything to the console for each cast, gives you a more reasonable result:

```
object obj = new A();
int iterations = 1000000000;

Stopwatch sw = Stopwatch.StartNew();
for (int i = 0; i < iterations; i++) {
  var res = obj as A;
  if (res != null) {
    res.MyProperty = 10;
  }
}
sw.Stop();
Console.WriteLine("obj is A (as)" + sw.Elapsed);

Stopwatch sw2 = Stopwatch.StartNew();
for (int i = 0; i < iterations; i++) {
  if (obj.GetType() == typeof(A)) {
    A a = (A)obj;
    a.MyProperty = 10;
  }
}
sw2.Stop();
Console.WriteLine("obj is A (GetType)" + sw2.Elapsed);

Stopwatch sw3 = Stopwatch.StartNew();
for (int i = 0; i < iterations; i++) {
  var isA = obj is A;
  if (isA) {
    A a = (A)obj;
    a.MyProperty = 19;
  }
}
sw3.Stop();
Console.WriteLine("obj is A (is)" + sw3.Elapsed);
```

Example output:

```
obj is A (as)00:00:00.3937249
obj is A (GetType)00:00:00.3452988
obj is A (is)00:00:01.0193541
```

Comment: I'm sure it's the first use of *something* that's causing the first test to be slower. I'm not sure whether it can be the use of console, since by the time the `WriteLine` call is issued, `sw.Elapsed` has already been evaluated (and formatted into a string).

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever: Good point, the `WriteLine` is actually outside the time, when I think of it. It could be something like memory management that gives the varying results when timing only a single cast.

Comment: In my case using your code gives (as) 6secs, (getType) - 11secs and (is) - 7secs, but the main idea of your explanations I understood.

Answer (score 2):

Your measurements are incorrect if they show that "as" is slower than "is".

The reason that can't be the case is that both the "as" and the "is" keywords generate an [`isinst`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.emit.opcodes.isinst.aspx) IL instruction, but the "is" instruction generates an additional check of the return value.

You do not need to perform any timings to determine this, because you can examine the generated IL code using reflector.

For example, this method:

```
static bool isTest(object value)
{
    return value is Random;
}
```

Generates this IL:

```
.method private hidebysig static bool isTest(object 'value') cil managed
{
    .maxstack 8
    L_0000: ldarg.0 
    L_0001: isinst [mscorlib]System.Random
    L_0006: ldnull 
    L_0007: cgt.un 
    L_0009: ret 
}
```

While this:

```
static object asTest(object value)
{
    return value as Random;
}
```

Generates:

```
.method private hidebysig static object asTest(object 'value') cil managed
{
    .maxstack 8
    L_0000: ldarg.0 
    L_0001: isinst [mscorlib]System.Random
    L_0006: ret 
}
```

The "is" keyword generates identical IL to the "as" keyword plus some additional instructions; therefore, "is" *must* be slower than "as" for this kind of usage.